# Mongoose, reference an item in an array

Tags: mongoose

```
let itemSchema = new Schema({
  description: String,
  evaluations: [
    {
      evaluation: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'evaluation',
        required: true,
        index: true
      },
      selection: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: '????', // How do i reference to 'selection' field here?
        required: true,
        index: true
      }
    }
  ]

let evaluationSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  selections: [
    {
      name: {type: String, required: true }, 
      value: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 15 },
    }
  ],
});
```

Is it possible to make a reference to an item in the selections array? How is this syntax written? Can't find in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify collection name of model first for both the schemas and then in ref put the collection name of evaluationSchema,

Another you cannot refrence a field you can only refrence a schema(Refrencing a field can be done in mongodb aggregation with $project)

```
let itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  description: String,
  evaluations: [
    {
      evaluation: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Eval',
        required: true,
        index: true
      },
      selection: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Eval', // How do i reference to 'selection' field here?
        required: true,
        index: true
      }
    }
  ]
});

mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);

let evaluationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  selections: [
    {
      name: {type: String, required: true }, 
      value: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 15 },
    }
  ],
});
 mongoose.model("Eval", evaluationSchema);
```